# One cover...several body pdfs

Tags: pdf, batch-processing, adobe-acrobat, booklet

I have a folder with 200 different complete 4-6 page pdfs. Doc1, Doc2, etc. One for each customer.

I want to attach a single 2-3 cover pdf to each of them, and save the resulting bunch...Doc1a, Doc2a, etc.

I know how to do them one at a time. But I have 200.

How do I batch this?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the cover is always the same?

Comment: See the [same Q on Superuser](http://superuser.com/q/389760/238753)

Answer (score 2):

One could do this using a script w/in InDesign or Acrobat --- I'd write up an AppleScript, but no access to my Mac at the moment.

Simpler to use a tool such as pdftk or pdftex. The former is intended for this sort of operation:

- download and install PDFtk Server from: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/
- create a batch file which calls pdftk once for each .pdf which you need to make:

  pdftk A=Cover.pdf B=Doc1.pdf cat A B output Doc1A.pdf

I usually make the .bat file up in a spreadsheet, then copy-paste it into a plain text editor and replace tabs w/ spaces or nothing as appropriate. There are command line options which would allow one to execute the command for all the files in a directory, but I just find it easier to be able to review what will happen first.

Comment: Acrobat does support scripting, so a script that inserts pages from a PDF, with a "close and save" should also be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Good point. I've added scripting Acrobat as an option.